# Impressão do cabeçalho da primeira página é diferente das outras restantes

Tags: crystal-reports

Fiz um mapa crystal reports e ao imprimir o report para papel em físico. O cabeçalho da Primeira página é impresso perfeitamente e a partir da segunda página a altura do cabeçalho é aumentado.
Alguém pode ajudar como ultrapassar esse desafio sff?
[image: Página com altura anormal]

[image: Página com altura normal, funcionando bem.]
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei bem ao certo se isso ira resolver devido a sua pergunta tente conferir as seguintes configurações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

pode ser também que seja algo referente a ajuste automático.

caso não resolva a sua duvida insira mais informações na pergunta ou algo que passa identificar melhor o que precisa.